# how to iterate over the connected vertices sequentially of polygon?

Tags: vertices, coordinates

I have a map where each country is a polygon of many vertices. I want to get an array of coordinates of the vertices of a polygon.[image]
Now I get and save the list of selected vertices in the table in edit mode, but these vertices are listed in random order. I want the script to indicate vertices that follow one another along the outer edge of the polygon.
Here is the script with which I now get the coordinates I need.

```
import bpy
import bmesh

obj = bpy.context.edit_object
me = obj.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
bm.faces.active = None

outputFile = 'E:/Documents/blender/mesh.csv'
f = open( outputFile, 'w' )
f.writelines('X' + ';')
f.writelines('Y' + ';')
f.writelines('Z' + '\n')

for v in bm.verts:
    if v.select:
      f.writelines(";".join( [str(round(v,3)) for v in tuple(v.co)]) + '\n')
f.close()
```

But how do I iterate over the connected vertices sequentially of polygon?

Comment: I don't know if it's always the case but I tested it on a random mesh and `for v in mesh.polygons[i].vertices: print(v)` returns the ordered indices of the polygon

Comment: if Gorigious answer doesn't work you can loop over the edges and find out the right order for the vertices

Comment: @Gorgious, this is exactly what I need. I am very grateful for the help